# Using gulp with request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, gulp

I have the following `Gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

const gulp    = require('gulp'),
      request = require('request');

const paths = {
  vendor: [
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-dist/master/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js'
  ]
};

gulp.task('vendor', (res) => {
  const url = request.get(paths.vendor).pipe(res);
  return gulp.src(url)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/vendor'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('vendor'));
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: options.uri is a required argument
```

With this method I trying to dicthing client-side package managers, like Bower. Is there a way to use `request` with `gulp` and looping through a list of object?

**EDIT:**

I placed this code for testing, only returning the first line from the loop:

```
gulp.task('vendor', () => {
  for (let i=0; i<paths.vendor.length; i++) {
    return console.log(paths.vendor[i]);
  };
});
```

Just like:

```
gulp.task('vendor', (res) => {
  const url = request.get(paths.vendor[index++]).pipe(res);
  return gulp.src(url)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/vendor'));
});
```

Comment: `request.get({ uri: paths.vendor })`

Comment: I've got this error message: `Error: Invalid URI "/"`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot pass a URL to `gulp.src()`. The `gulp` instance inherits `src()` and `dest()` from  [`vinyl-fs`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs) meaning you can only use it to read from and write to the local file system.

Try [`gulp-download`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-download) instead, which wraps `request` into a vinyl stream:

```
var download = require('gulp-download');

gulp.task('vendor', () => {
  return download(paths.vendor)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/vendor'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.get` only works on one URI at a time and you are passing an array, also AFAIK `parallel` expects a list of tasks, not one task that processes many items. Maybe this would work for you:

```
'use strict';

const gulp    = require('gulp'),
      request = require('request');

const paths = {
  vendor: [
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-dist/master/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js'
  ]
};
let index = 0;

gulp.task('vendor', (res) => {
  const url = request.get(paths.vendor[index++]).pipe(res);
  return gulp.src(url)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/vendor'));
});

let parallelTasks = (new Array(paths.vendor.length)).fill('vendor');

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel(...parallelTasks));
```

Comment: `parallel` is stripped down code like the whole, so it has more tasks. Sorry for didn't mentoining.

Comment: I've got `TypeError: dest.on is not a function` error at `.pipe(res);`.

Comment: Updated my question.